# Change socketio config dynamically

Tags: angular, ngx-socket-io

I am using ngx-socket-io for realtime notifications in angular app

My current requirement is to enable notifications or socketio requests to server only if enabled in settings DB

I was thinking to make this change by changing the socketio module config during runtime, i.e. when I get the settings from API call.

My current code in app.module:

```js
if(environment.angularEnv == "local") {
  config = { url: 'http://localhost:8001', options: {} };
} else {
  config = { url: location.origin, options: {} };
}
```

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
```

Comment: I would advise extending the socket.io client and implementing your own initialization functions

Comment: then instead of injecting the ```Socket``` service in your component, you would inject your ```MySocket``` that will have a function to change the config